# Establish SSH conection from one Lan-interface to an other Lan-interface via Port-Forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, lan

Situation: local PC is in the Network A and my Pi is in the network B. Network A and B are connected to two different interfaces of Router B (eth1, eth0).

```
PC (1.1.1.10)----- switch-----Router A (no Admin)---- INTERNET  
                    |
               /----/
               |
    eth1(1.1.1.20)-|Router B (i am Admin)|-(2.2.2.1)eth0------PI-server(2.2.2.2)
```

I got a port forwarding rule on the Router B: 1.1.1.20 port:1000 --> 2.2.2.2:22

If I try to connect from PC:

```
ssh pi@1.1.1.20 -p 1000
```

I only get Connection timed out after a while.

I set in the sshd_config `GatewayPorts yes` (not sure if necessary).
I can see (in the web GUI of Router B) that same traffic is coming in the network interface eth0 when I try to connect.

My guess is: I can reach the Pi but the packets from the Pi are not coming back to my PC. 
All IP addresses are not the real ones of course.

Ah, one think. In the port forwarding rule eth0 is set as LAN and eth1 as WAN, but eth1 is not really WAN, but I have too pick WAN and LAN, there is no option like LAN to LAN. Maybe that's a problem.

(The PC can be found by his IP 1.1.1.10 via Internet, if this information is helpful)

Can anyone help my? I hope I covered all necessary information, it's my first time hear :)

Comment: Please consider creating ASCII graphics in a code block.

Comment: If router B is a regular router (not doing any NAT magic), you can add a static route on PC for 2.2.2.0/24 via 1.1.1.20/32. This will send packets destined for 2.2.2.2 not to Router A, but to Router B.

Comment: It is correct to think eth1 is WAN and eth0 is LAN in the Router B. And you've done all correctly, there may be some subtle things. Please ensure Pi has a default route to via 2.2.2.1. Also, did you tried to run `tcpdump` there and ensure it really sends answers back to your SSH packets?

Comment: @nikita thanks for the tcpdump tip. Just searched for a tool like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for the quick reply. It works now.
The solution was a reset to factory settings for router B. Than i used the wizard to set up B as normal internet Router and added the port forwarding rule as before.
Not sure what the problem was, but it works now.

And special thanks to Nikita for the tcpdump tip. Will be very us full in the future for me.